# Satisfying Cross tab constraints in Python by filling in Random Numbers

Tags: python, pandas, constraints, crosstab

I have a problem to modify a dataframe (actual data) to satisfy cross tab constraints and generating a new dataframe as described below:

In cross-tab 1 (attached pic n code), we have 2 tasks for John in Area A, 1 task for John in Area B and so on. However, my desired distribution is as shown in cross-tab 2 i.e., John has 1 task in Area A, 4 tasks in Area B etc. Thus I need to modify original data as depicted by crosstab 1, to satisfy the row and column totals constraints as required in crosstab2, while grand total should remain 18 as in both cross tabs. Number filling may be random

Another constraint is average time which should be for example 11 minutes for John (average of 03 tasks), 7 minutes for William and 5 minutes for Richard(03 tasks).

Thus, the task is to modify original dataframe which satisfies row, column total as in crosstab2 and average time requirement. The final dataframe will have three columns Person, Area of Work and Time and will generate a crosstab similar to crosstab2, while randomly filling in numbers

[Cross tab2- Required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iryyc.jpg)

[Cross tab1- Actual Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1ia8.jpg)

1. Actual Data:

   df = pd.DataFrame([['John','A',2,8],['John','B',1,9],['John','C',0,12],['William','A',1,14],['William','B',2,10],['William','C',2,9],['Richard','A',3,8],['Richard','B',4,7],['Richard','C',3,5]],columns=['Person', 'AreaOfWork', 'Task','Time'])

1.1  Actual Cross-Tab:

```
pd.crosstab(df.AreaOfWork, df.Person, values=df.Task, aggfunc=np.sum, margins=True)
```

2. Required-Dataframe

   df1 = pd.DataFrame([['John','A',1,10],['John','B',4,11],['John','C',3,12],['William','A',0,9],['William','B',1,7],['William','C',3,5],['Richard','A',2,5],['Richard','B',1,3],['Richard','C',3,8]],columns=['Person', 'AreaOfWork', 'Task','Time'])

2.1  Required crosstab

```
pd.crosstab(df.AreaOfWork, df.Person, values=df1.Task, aggfunc=np.sum, margins=True)
```

Comment: What are your input data? Also can you add code, what you try?

Comment: Input data and actual cross tab, required dataframe and required cross tab updated in question above.

Comment: Thank you. But I dont understand formula - how you get your desired output form input? I try count `mean` form input and get something else - `(8+9+12)/3=9.666` for `John` Can you explain more? Thanks.

Comment: The desired output, I entered manually. The actual dataframe values should be adjusted automatically in a way that the desired dataframe/crosstab is obtained. This is the problem of constraint satisfaction, adjusting data in a way that row and column totals value are satisfied.